# Getting multiple SELECT queries into a single result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have multiple join SQL queries and I want to return a single result set:

e.g.

```
select t1.a, t2.b from test t1. 
join test2 t2 on t1.c =t2.d

select t3.x, t4.y from test3 t3. 
join test4 t4 on t3.p =t4.q
```

Result set should be

```
a b   x y
----------
2 abc 3 4
```

Comment: If there are two rows in each table, which row in a/b goes with which row in x/y? What happens if there are three rows in a/b and only two rows in x/y?

Comment: this could be also possibility

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, but you will have a cartesian product.

```
select  t1.a,
        t2.b,
        t3.c,
        t4.d 
from    test1 t1
join    test2 t2 on t1.c=t2.d
join    test3 t3 on 1=1
join    test4 t4 on t3.p=t4.q
```

Comment: could I know any alternate way? becoz there will be where condition also attached to each sql query.

Comment: Then you need to ask a COMPLETE question. We've already uncovered two things you've left out and have yet to actually describe.